# Nodemailer Oauth2 error : unauthorized_client

Tags: node.js, email, oauth, gmail-api, nodemailer

I'am trying to send mail using Oauth and nodemailer on a nodejs app, I did it without Oauth but my password was wrote in the code so I turn myself to Oauth.

I only want to connect myself to send mail in an automatic way.
I have settup a project and a service account on google cloud platform. I added the gmail api and wrote some code :

```
 var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host:'smtp.gmail.com',
   port:465,
   secure:true,
   auth:{
     type: 'OAuth2',
     user: 'thomas.legrand.test@gmail.com',
     serviceClient:config.client_id,
     privateKey:config.private_key
   }
 });
 var mail = {
   from: "thomas.legrand.test@gmail.com",
   to: "thomas.legrand26@gmail.com",
   subject:"Un sujet abstrait",
   html:"<h1> Ceci est un mail de test </h1><h2> et ceci un sous titre </h2> "
 };

 smtpTransport.on('token', token => {
    console.log('A new access token was generated');
    console.log('User: %s', token.user);
    console.log('Access Token: %s', token.accessToken);
    console.log('Expires: %s', new Date(token.expires));
});

smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
        if(error) {
          console.log("Erreur lors de l'envoie du mail ");
          console.log(error);
        }else {
          console.log("succes")
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
      });
```

But I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9z9j.png) (unauthorized_client) which I can't solve.

I hope you can help me or give me hints at least !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify you follow these steps to be sure you set in the right way your client:

- [Setting up API keys](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en).

And then don't forget to enable your Gmail API as it is said here:

- [Enable and disable APIs](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en).

Also, I would recommend you to check the [Gmail API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

Comment: I think i'm on the good way ! I did the last link you put and now i got a new error : invalid_grant, i'll search by myself. 
Thank you

Comment: you're welcome! Consider mark my answer as the best answer if it helped you

Comment: This is a great [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-nodemailer-to-send-emails-from-your-node-js-server/](article) from freeCodeCamp. But, in the transport settings work for me is `service:'gmail', scope: 'https://mail.google.com', auth{type, user, clientId, ClientSecret, refreshToken, accessToken}`

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine but make sure the following things :

1. The correct OAuth2 scope for Gmail SMTP is https://mail.google.com/, make sure your client has this scope set when requesting permissions for an user.
2. Make sure that Gmail API access is enabled for your Client ID. To do this, search for the Gmail API in Google API Manager and click on “enable”

Also, Make sure clientId and private key is being passed properly.

Answer (score 0):

if by any chance you are using these values in a .env file. ensure you restart the server after making changes. I missed this and it took my some minutes to figure out that was my problem